# execute a javascript on load

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to execute this java script on load, but it doesn't seem to display the result after 
the browser loads.

```
<script>
    function displayNumber()
{



var card = document.getElementById('credit').value;

var str = "";
for(var i=1; i <= card.length-4; i++) {
   str += "*";
}

    ecard = str + card.substr(card.length-4);
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = ecard;

}
</script>


  <form id="myform">
   <input type="text" id="credit"  onLoad="displayNumber()" value="123456789012">
</form> 

<label id="output"> </label>
```

The output should be

```
********9012
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `onload` with an `input`. Instead, put `window.onload = displayNumber;` in your JavaScript. The other option is to add a body tag and use `onload="displayNumber()"`